# Toggle locale of Date Picker Content Control in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, datepicker, locale, word-contentcontrol

I am trying to assist someone in producing a template to be used with different languages: EnglishUK and Spanish.

I have a sample document with two DatePicker Content Controls. In the document, they look like this:

[image: screenshot]

Here is a [temporary link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vf7rmo2t1di79gt/deleteme%20date%20picker%20locale%20swap.docm?dl=0) to that document.

The code is:

```
Sub DatePickerLocaleToggle()
    ' Charles Kenyon
    Dim cc As ContentControl
    For Each cc In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
        If cc.Type = wdContentControlDate Then
            If cc.DateDisplayLocale = wdEnglishUK Then
                cc.DateDisplayLocale = wdSpanish
            Else
                If cc.DateDisplayLocale = wdSpanish Then
                    cc.DateDisplayLocale = wdEnglishUK
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cc
End Sub
```

According to [Microsoft's Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.contentcontrol.datedisplaylocale?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm266534935);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue), this is a Read/Write property.

The code works if the date has no value set, but it does not convert the English Date to the Spanish Date or vice versa if there is a date already there. A new date picked will use the correct locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub DatePickerLocaleToggle()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim CCtrl As ContentControl
For Each CCtrl In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
  With CCtrl
    If .Type = wdContentControlDate Then
      Select Case .DateDisplayLocale
        Case wdEnglishUK
          If .ShowingPlaceholderText = True Then
            .DateDisplayLocale = wdSpanish
            .SetPlaceholderText Text:="Haga clic o toque para ingresar una fecha "
          Else
            .Range.Text = CCtrlDt(CCtrl, .DateDisplayFormat, wdSpanish)
          End If
        Case wdSpanish
          If .ShowingPlaceholderText = True Then
            .DateDisplayLocale = wdEnglishUK
            .SetPlaceholderText Text:="Click or tap to enter a date"
          Else
            .Range.Text = CCtrlDt(CCtrl, .DateDisplayFormat, wdEnglishUK)
          End If
      End Select
    End If
  End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function CCtrlDt(CCtrl As ContentControl, StrFMt As String, Lang As Long) As String
Dim StrTmp As String, StrSplit As String, StrMnth As String, i As Long, Dt As Date
With CCtrl
  For i = 0 To UBound(Split(StrFMt, " "))
    StrSplit = Split(StrFMt, " ")(i)
    If InStr(StrSplit, "ddd") = 0 Then
      If InStr(StrSplit, "M") = 1 Then
        StrMnth = Left(Split(.Range.Text, " ")(i), 3)
        If Lang = wdEnglishUK Then
          Select Case LCase(StrMnth)
            Case "ene": StrMnth = "Jan"
            Case "feb": StrMnth = "Feb"
            Case "mar": StrMnth = "Mar"
            Case "abr": StrMnth = "Apr"
            Case "may": StrMnth = "May"
            Case "jun": StrMnth = "Jun"
            Case "jul": StrMnth = "Jul"
            Case "ago": StrMnth = "Aug"
            Case "sep": StrMnth = "Sep"
            Case "oct": StrMnth = "Oct"
            Case "nov": StrMnth = "Nov"
            Case "dic": StrMnth = "Dec"
          End Select
        End If
        StrTmp = StrTmp & StrMnth & " "
      Else
        StrTmp = StrTmp & Split(.Range.Text, " ")(i) & " "
      End If
    End If
  Next
  Dt = CDate(Trim(StrTmp))
  .DateDisplayLocale = Lang
  CCtrlDt = Format(Dt, StrFMt)
End With
End Function
```

Comment: I added your macro and function to the sample document along with various Content Controls in case anyone wants to see it in action. https://www.dropbox.com/s/vf7rmo2t1di79gt/deleteme%20Date%20Picker%20Locale%20Swap.docm?dl=0

Comment: I've made some minor edits to the code to simplify it.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the sample/test document with your revisions.